# Returned an extra printed result "[1] 36" from for loop: How to remove it?

Tags: r

```
#Create a function to print squares of numbers in sequence
squareseq <- function(a) {
   for(i in 1:a) {
      b <- i^2
      result <- print(b)
   }
   return(result)
}

# Call the function supplying 6 as an argument
squareseq(6)
```

The result of calling the function above, is shown below:

```
[1] 1
[1] 4
[1] 9
[1] 16
[1] 25
[1] 36
[1] 36
```

How do I keep "return(result)" but remove the duplicated line: "[1] 36"? So I get this result below:

```
[1] 1
[1] 4
[1] 9
[1] 16
[1] 25
[1] 36
```

Comment: Just do `(1:6)^2`, which is how this calculation is intended to be done in R.  Your teacher will be impressed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `invisible`:

```
squareseq <- function(a) {
  for(i in 1:a) {
    b <- i^2
    result <- print(b)
  }
  invisible(result)
}

squareseq(6)
#[1] 1
#[1] 4
#[1] 9
#[1] 16
#[1] 25
#[1] 36
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, it prints the right result, but can you use "return" in this instance than using "invisible" to get the same right result?

Comment: You can write `return(invisible(result))` but the `return` call is superfluous.

Answer (score 3):

My answer is going to be old fashion theortical here.

Problem in your approach is first you are printing values in `for` loop so whenever function is called it will print as per argument(all numbers). Now when function comes out of that loop you are returning the value which will return latest value of variable named result in your case, that is the actually reason only last item is being printed 2 times(because item is already printed previously and now getting returned).

As per @Roland's comments I have edited my answer now(where it was saying do not return anything in function, seems to be not applicable with R). Since it is mandatory to return a value in R so pleaseuse @DiceboyT's nice solution using `invisible`.

Comment: R functions always return something, at least `NULL`. It's impossible to avoid that.

Comment: @Roland, thanks a TON for letting me know, I am learning `R` I went with shell/c/awk's mindset(sorry for that), so how about if to avoid this last item's double printing if we write it like `return ""` OR `return null` where null could be variable, since it is having no value so NULL will be returned. Will be grateful if you could let me know on this, I will edit my answer then.

Comment: The top answer already shows what you do in R. You return invisibly.

Comment: @Roland, thank you, I have already mentioned about top answer and edited my answer too as per your comments, thanks a TON for guiding here.